# Obtain an element with a dynamically generated ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very straightforward thing I am trying to do, but am new to Javascript.

I have an HTML page which generates a series of DIV elements with an ID that is dynamically generated.

Example: `<div id="shots_234"></div>`, `<div id="shots_256"></div>`

I am making a jQuery AJAX request, and I want to populate the html with the response targetting one of those IDs.

```
function WeddingsShotDown(shotid, segmentid) {

    document.getElementById('ShotDownId').value = shotid;

    var form = document.getElementById('ShotDown');
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var id = "shots_" + segmentid;
    var divid = document.getElementById(id);

    console.log("Div: " + divid);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Weddings/ShotDown',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'html',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $("#shots_" + segmentid).html(response);
                document.getElementById('ShotId').value = "";
                showNotification("success", "Your shot sequence has been updated", "far fa-check-circle");
            } else {
                showNotification("danger", "Error saving shot sequence", "far fa-check-circle");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So neither

```
$("#shots_" + segmentid).html(response);
```

Nor

```
    var id = "shots_" + segmentid;
    var divid = document.getElementById(id);
```

Get me the div that I want.

How can I update that element?

Comment: try ```document.getElementById("shots_234").innerHTML = "UPDATE";``` obviously in this case it would change your div to a text item saying "UPDATE" but change it to whatever you want it to be

Comment: If neither of those give you the element you want, than you have a problem with your HTML elements. So does `console.log("Div: " + divid);` log null?

Comment: @NeonFire if I type that in literally it works, however the 234 part is dynamic  based upon something thsat has been clicked.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, it logs null. Unless I type in the div ID as a string rather than a concatenated value then it will not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Var segmentid not exist in the success function. Try, save id in the request with beforeSend, and get in the receive:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Weddings/ShotDown',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'html',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend:function( jqXHR ){
            jqXHR.id = segmentid;
        }
    }).done(function(response, msgStatus, jqXHR){
        if (response) {
                $("#shots_" + jqXHR.id).html(response);
                document.getElementById('ShotId').value = "";
                showNotification("success", "Your shot sequence has been updated", "far fa-check-circle");
            } else {
                showNotification("danger", "Error saving shot sequence", "far fa-check-circle");
            }
    });
```

Comment: This is still finding `$("#shots_" + jqXHR.id)` is null

Comment: Correction - this does work :-) thanks!